# Plotting multiple graphs in separate tkinter figures within the same window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI using tkinter that will plot multiple plots when prompted. Right now my code works and it plots all of the graphs onto one figure. I would like to plot the graphs on separate figures, in the same GUI.

This is my code that plots all of the graphs in the same tkinter figure:

```
import myModule
from myModule import *
import SA_apis
from SA_apis import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,   NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
NORM_FONT= ("Verdana", 10)
SMALL_FONT= ("Verdana", 8)
plt.style.use("dark_background")
plt.style.use("seaborn-bright")

def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Menu")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=NORM_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()


class TkGraph(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "TkGraph")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = lambda: popupmsg("This is not yet supported"))
        filemenu.add_command(label="Add", command = lambda: popupmsg("This is not yet supported"))
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        parameter = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        parameter.add_command(label="Selection", command = lambda: popupmsg("This is not yet supported"))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Parameter", menu=parameter)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        timemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        timemenu.add_command(label="Selection", command = lambda: popupmsg("This is not yet supported"))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Time", menu=parameter)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Selection", command = lambda: popupmsg("This is not yet supported"))
         menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=parameter)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

         self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
         self.show_frame(StartPage)
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph",
        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()


 class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

    """This is the code for the plotted graph, for each parameter you wish to plot you need to have a seperate x, y coordinate system.
    You got the amount of points for each parameter on SA_apis now you just paste that number in the code."""

    #Graph Code
    x = (g[0].time[:111673])
    y = (g[0].data.f[:111673])
    x2 = (h[0].time[:142642])
    y2 = (h[0].data.f[:142642])
    x3 = (j[0].time[:134970])
    y3 = j[0].data.f[:134970]
    x4 = (p[0].time[:147542])
    y4 = (p[0].data.f[:147542])
    plt.subplot()
    fig = plt.figure()

    """For each parameters x,y coordinates you will need a seperate  plt.plot()"""
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.plot(x2, y2)
    plt.plot(x3, y3)
    plt.plot(x4, y4)
    #descr = (g[0].descr)
    plt.title('(descr)', fontsize = 15)
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Data', fontsize=12)
    plt.grid(linestyle = 'dashed')   

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

app = TkGraph()
app.mainloop()
```

[image]
 I tried separating the graphs like this:

```
    x = (g[0].time[:111673])
    y = (g[0].data.f[:111673])
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.title('(descr)', fontsize = 15)
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Data', fontsize=12)
    plt.grid(linestyle = 'dashed')
    fig = plt.figure()

    x2 = (h[0].time[:142642])
    y2 = (h[0].data.f[:142642])
    plt.plot(x2, y2)
    plt.title('(descr)', fontsize = 15)
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Data', fontsize=12)
    plt.grid(linestyle = 'dashed')
    fig = plt.figure()

    x3 = (j[0].time[:134970])
    y3 = (j[0].data.f[:134970])
    plt.plot(x3, y3)
    plt.title('(descr)', fontsize = 15)
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Data', fontsize=12)
    plt.grid(linestyle = 'dashed')
    fig = plt.figure()

    x4 = (p[0].time[:147542])
    y4 = (p[0].data.f[:147542])
    plt.plot(x4, y4)
    plt.title('(descr)', fontsize = 15)
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Data', fontsize=12)
    plt.grid(linestyle = 'dashed')
    fig = plt.figure()
```

But this is tedious,  and doesn't result in all four graphs being plotted in the same tkinter window. This causes and empty tkinter.

MY QUESTION IS THIS: How can I plot multiple graphs in the same tkinter window but in different figures. Ideally they would be plotted next to each other I don't want to create another window. I need the graphs to all be viewed at the same time for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use the `Frame` widgets.

You can have more than one frame in the same window so you create each frame you need for each graph and work with them that way.

Seeing that you are already using frames it should not be hard for you to set up.

Answer (score -2):

you need to put parameter in the subplot method.

```
plt.subplot(421)
plt.xlabel('Time in seconds')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('%s HeartBeat ..' % beat_file1)
plt.plot(timeArray1, Y_filtered1)

plt.subplot(422)
plt.xlabel('Time in seconds')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('%s HeartBeat ..' % beat_file2)
plt.plot(timeArray2, Y_filtered2)
```

There is an example here : https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. What is '421,'422'  'Time in seconds', 'Amplitude',  and 'HeartBeat' and how do they relate to my code? You haven't provided me with enough information about the code that you posted to my answer. You link is to a code that used numpy I have used pandas dataframe.

Comment: This is just a program that I made. When i did that, i wanted to plot four graph on the same window so with the plt.subplot method you can do that. Take a square example. If you want to display 4 graphs, The first graph have this : 'plt.subplot(221)' this is how to put the first graph on the left corner. etc ...

Comment: You have an example in the link .. Just look :) don't see the other line just look the subplot() method