# How can I display two graphs with Tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Hello I have a code and I would like to display my two graphs on the same figure. Here is my code :

```
import Tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

app = tk.Tk()
app.wm_title("Graphs")

fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=96)
a = np.array([1,2,3])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bx = fig.add_subplot(111)
bx.plot(a,np.array([0,0.5,2]))


graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=app)
canvas = graph.get_tk_widget()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan = 11, padx =10, pady =5)

def updateScale(value):
   ax.clear()
   print "scale is now %s" % (value)
   #a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
   b = float(value)*a
   ax.plot(a,b)
   graph.show()

value = tk.DoubleVar()
scale = tk.Scale(app, variable=value, orient="horizontal",length = 100, from_=0.55, to=2.75, resolution = 0.01,command=updateScale)
scale.grid(row=0, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```

Everything is okay except that I don't watch bx... Any suggestions ? Thank you !

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328966/plotting-multiple-graphs-in-separate-tkinter-figures-within-the-same-window) - you can add multiple frames into one windows and you can use each for a graph. it´s with an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584805/in-matplotlib-what-does-the-argument-mean-in-fig-add-subplot111#11404223 also take a look here, looks like you add both sub-plots with (111) which maybe leads to overlapping

Comment: Actually I want these two plots in the same subplot. But the problem is in the function updateScale(value) I have ax.clear() and I just want to clear plot(a,b)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use two different subplots here. Instead you can take the same axes to plot to. Then don't use `clear`, since it destroys the initial graph. Instead only update an existing line. If `line, = axp.plot()`, `line.set_data()` will set new data to the line. Then rescale the axes and draw the canvas.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

app = tk.Tk()
app.wm_title("Graphs")

fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=96)
a = np.array([1,2,3])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

line, = ax.plot(a,np.array([0,0.5,2]))
line2, = ax.plot(a,0.55*a)

graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=app)
canvas = graph.get_tk_widget()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan = 11, padx =10, pady =5)

def updateScale(value):
   print "scale is now %s" % (value)
   b = float(value)*a
   # set new data to the line
   line2.set_data(a,b)
   # rescale the axes
   ax.relim()
   ax.autoscale()
   #draw canvas
   fig.canvas.draw_idle()


value = tk.DoubleVar()
scale = tk.Scale(app, variable=value, orient="horizontal",length = 100, 
                 from_=0.55, to=2.75, resolution = 0.01,command=updateScale)
scale.grid(row=0, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```